# I need some addvice with visual studio C# in basicly doing division depending on what is checked in a checklistbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

hello i need some help dividing a variable based on witch of the boxes are checked in order of the biggest value checked first to give me a result of how many parts one would need of each type.
[image: My Checklistbox]

for example  in this following image.
[image: Example]
I need 48 digital inputs so the result i'm looking to get is 1 32-point card and 1 16-point card.

i want to enter an amount by digital inputs say 48 like in example picture, and based on what is checked by the "Cards available" area in the "DI" checkbox list it should divide the value of "Digital inputs" by 32 if the "32-point" is checked and 16 if the "16-point" is checked to calculate how many cards i have to buy of each type in order of biggest(64-point) to smallest(4-point) and display it by cards needed by the "cards needed" area. as in example i need 48 digital inputs and i have 32-point unit and 16-point unit available it should display i need 1x 32-point card and 1x16-point card

it should display the result by the "Çards needed" area in a label or textbox

To be honest i have no idea how to even aproach this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's unlcear what you are asking. You want to enter a number into "Digital Inputs" and your program should automatically check the needed numbers in "DI"?

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: i want to enter an amount by digital inputs say 48 like in example picture, and based on what is checked by the "Cards available" area in the "DI" checkbox list it should divide the value of "Digital inputs" by 32 if the "32-point" is checked and 16 if the  "16-point" is checked to calculate how many cards i have to buy of each type in order of biggest(64-point) to smallest(4-point) and display it by cards needed by the "cards needed" area. as in example i need 48 digital inputs and i have 32-point unit and 16-point unit available it should display i need 1x 32-point card and 1x16-point card

Comment: it should display the result by the "Çards needed" area in a label or textbox

Comment: Please edit your question with the new input. No one should have to read all comments in order to know about the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution idea that should get you started:

```cs
var digitalInputs = 48;
var availableCards = new[] { 32, 16 };

var cardsNeeded = availableCards.ToDictionary(c => c, _ => 0);

for (int i = 0; i < availableCards.Length; i++) {
    var card = availableCards[i];
    while (card <= digitalInputs) {
        digitalInputs -= card;
        cardsNeeded[card]++;
    }
}
```

The idea is to go through all available cards in descending order. If the current card is less than or equal to your digital inputs than subtract that card's value from digital inputs and store one usage of that card in `neededCards`. Keep doing that until the current card is too big to "fit" into the remaining digital inputs. After that go to the next available card and do the same.

At the end `cardsNeeded` will contain the required amount for each card.